Receiver used for CORS (stations)?
I'm using a UBLOX NEO-F9P receiver and they are great value. In association with NTRIP and a local CORS I'm getting cm level accuracy, after a FIX.  I was wondering what is the preferred/recommended hardware for a CORS station ?

If you wanting to set up your own base station (wouldn't be a CORS station unless it is continuously operated in the same spot). You could just get a second f9p receiver and a tripod mounted survey antenna and some radios to link them up. ArduSimple has various budget friendly kits based on the f9p receivers that you could look at.  Suggesting this because your currently using f9p hardware.
If your just curious what hardware is used in CORS stations.  They typically use choke ring antennas and "reference station" receivers from companies like Leica Geosystems.

Arlen, thanks for the inputs.
